# Flushbar not displaying error messages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, exception, flushbar

I was following this Flutter Course on YouTube, the person writes exact same code, but he gets to see the error message on screen (front-end) through FlushBar, but when I do the same thing, I only receive the same error, but not through FlushBar (front-end), I only receive the error in debugMode terminal of VSCode.

I am receiving the 'Login Successful' message through FlushBar properly on screen, but when I write an incorrect email just to check the API exceptions, so the error doesn't appear on the screen (front-end) and only shows me the error in debugMode.

So please guide me how can I receive the error through FlushBar on screen?

`I receive the error like this`

[image]

`YouTuber receives the error on screen through FlushBar`

[image]

`utils.dart`

```
import 'package:another_flushbar/flushbar_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:another_flushbar/flushbar.dart';

class Utils {
  static void fieldFocusChange(
      BuildContext context, FocusNode current, FocusNode nextFocus) {
    current.unfocus();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
  }

  static toastMessage(String message) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: message,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 20,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, // 1 second
    );
  }

  static void flushBarErrorMessages(String message, BuildContext context) {
    showFlushbar(
      context: context,
      flushbar: Flushbar(
        flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
        forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.decelerate,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        message: message,
        messageSize: 20,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.warning,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      )..show(context),
    );
  }

  static snakeBar(String message, BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`auth_view_model.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mvvm/repository/auth_repository.dart';

import '../utils/utils.dart';

class AuthViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final _myRepo = AuthRepository();

  Future<void> loginApi(dynamic data, BuildContext context) async {
    _myRepo.loginApi(data).then((value) {
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessages('Login Successful', context);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(value.toString());
      }
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          Utils.flushBarErrorMessages(error.toString(), context);
          print(error.toString());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`auth_repository.dart`

```
import 'package:mvvm/data/network/base_api_services.dart';
import 'package:mvvm/data/network/network_api_servcies.dart';
import 'package:mvvm/resources/app_url.dart';

class AuthRepository {
  BaseApiServices _apiServices = NetworkApiServices();

  Future<dynamic> loginApi(dynamic data) async {
    try {
      dynamic response =
          await _apiServices.getPostApiResponse(AppUrl.loginURL, data);

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> registerApi(dynamic data) async {
    try {
      dynamic response =
          await _apiServices.getPostApiResponse(AppUrl.registerApiURL, data);

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

`app_exceptions.dart`

```
class AppException implements Exception {
  final _message;
  final _prefix;
  AppException([this._message, this._prefix]);

  String toString() {
    return '$_prefix$_message';
  }
}

class FetchDataException extends AppException {
  FetchDataException([String? message])
      : super(message, 'Error during communication ');
}

class BadRequestException extends AppException {
  BadRequestException([String? message]) : super(message, 'Invalid Request ');
}

class UnauthorizedException extends AppException {
  UnauthorizedException([String? message])
      : super(message, ' Unauthorized Request ');
}

class InvalidInputException extends AppException {
  InvalidInputException([String? message]) : super(message, 'Invalid Input ');
}
```